# Xamarin.Forms View does not show keboard keyboard when we focus the EditText in Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-edittext

In Forms inherited from View and I have added EditText in Android project for that forms view by using custom render. And I have manually focused the view in button click dynamically. And now EditText has been focused but keyboard does not show.

Please find the Sample [here](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/TestTableView-1083630897)  for your reference

So to resolve the above issue by push to show the keyboard in EditText OnFocusChanged() by using the following code snippet. But when I have added the view inside of TableView in pcl, keyboard gitches when we tap the on that view.

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)this.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);

if (gainFocus)
{
    if (inputManager != null)
    {
        inputManager.ShowSoftInput(this, ShowFlags.Forced);
    }
}
else
{
    if (inputManager != null)
    {
        inputManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(this.WindowToken, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you get focus by `edit.Focus();` , your customView will get the focus, not the `EditText` in the custom renderer view. You can try to use `Entry` 's custom renderer(you do not need to add above code to monitor the focus as well), it worked in the `TableView ` normally, here is running gif. https://imgur.com/a/kJGhphM

Comment: In our scenario, we have used Native EditText, If am use Entry's renderer i need to change entire structure  of code. Please suggest to your valuable solution with Native EditText.